# SQL code works in phpMyAdmin but not in the PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm trying to make a form for a website where this form is used for participants in a competition, and when submitting the club a participant is in, the website will look for that clubs ID and put that number into the participants table.

The SQL code works in the SQL query page on the phpMyAdmin page, but not in the actual PHP file (on the website).

I don't get any error messages, except for the "NAY" that I've defined at the bottom of the code.

```
if(isset($_POST['Send'])){
    $query1 = "INSERT INTO Participants (FirstName, LastName, Gender, DateOfBirth, Team, CountryCode,City, ZipCode, Telephone, Email, ClubID)
               VALUES ('$FirstName', '$LastName', '$Gender', '$DateOfBirth', '$Team', '$CountryCode', '$City', '$ZipCode', '$Telephone', '$Email',
                    (SELECT ClubID
                     FROM Clubs
                     WHERE '$ClubName' = ClubName)
               )";

    if ($db->query($query1) === TRUE){
        echo "YAY";
    } else {
        echo "NAY";
    }
}
```

Comment: try print_r($db->errorInfo()); to see what's wrong.

Comment: I would say your where statement, in your sub select, is wrong, unless you have the field being dynamic. It should probably be: WHERE ClubName = '$ClubName'

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== TRUE`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.

Comment: Are you sure `$db->query($query1)` returns a boolean? You're using `===` instead of `==` which means it will fail unless it returns the true boolean

Comment: @Gerfried, if I replace `echo "NAY"` with `print_r($db->errorInfo());`, I get: _"Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::errorInfo()"_.
---- @UlrikMcArdle that didn't seem to do anything, so I think it's dynamic
---- @tadman I'm going to improve on those later on. Right now I'm just focusing on getting the SQL to actually work. But thanks for the links!
---- @FuzzyTree The `===` or `==` it didn't change the outcome, but I use the `==`now though.